# <!-- MENU-LOCATION=NONE --> dreamweaver cs5 error

Tags: dreamweaver

when ever i try to insert image or swf file in dreamweaver cs5. i am getting this error

also getting this error within head tags

anyone knows about it ?

Answer (score 0):

All other things being equal, it sounds like Dreamweaver has gone corrupt.  You may want to follow the steps in this KB article to reset the preferences.

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/839/cpsid_83912.html

If that doesn't fix it, an uninstall/reinstall usually does.